# Подскажите пожалуйста, ошибка при установке torch

Tags: python

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch (from versions: none)

ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch

Comment: Что вы хотите сделать?

Comment: установить Torch, но выдает ошибку ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PyTorch` не получится установится при помощи команды `pip install torch`.

Для установки вам нужно перейти на [официальный сайт](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/) и выбрать конфигурацию вашей системы, после чего установить `Package` в значение `pip` и система предоставит вам ссылку, которую нужно будет ввести в консоль для установки при помощи пакетного менеджера `pip`

Также, для работы `PyTorch`, должен быть предварительно установлен пакет `numpy`.

Comment: Сбой выполнения программы pip3.exe: Указанный исполняемый файл не является действительным приложением для этой операционной системы.строка:1 знак:1
+ pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio

Comment: Выдает вот такую ошибку.

Comment: @ergreg попробуйте написать pip, вместо pip3

Comment: ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch

Comment: @ergreg как альтернатива - можете попробовать установить через пакетный менеджер conda, там должно быть стабильнее

Comment: @ergreg ещё у них на сайте написано, что поддерживается python до версии 3.9 включительно, если у вас 3.10 или 3.11, то возможно проблема в этом, попробуйте откатиться.

Comment: @ergreg А какая у вас вообще ОС и какая версия питона? Торч для этой конфигурации точно существует?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в версии `python`. На данный момент последняя поддерживаемая версия `python` - `3.10`. Поэтому torch (2.xxx) пока работает с `python <= 3.10.x`.